# Python3 - How to import all with same string ending

Tags: python-3.x

I am importing my controllers explicitly like:

```
from controllers import UserController, GroupController, PermissionController, ...
```

but whenever I create another controller I need to add it in my import. Is there a way to import it like

```
from controllers import *Controller
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the parent module or package, and introspect it to
get the wanted names as strings - at this point any string comparison expression is valid - in your case, the `.endswith` method can check for the suffix.

## if the names are identifiers inside a file

When you import a module in Python, all of it is executed, and all functions classes and module-level variables on it are created.

The `from module import name`  syntax therefore just create  new binding in the current module, pointing the local  "name" variable to `module.name`.

So, if you are importing these names for local use in the current module, the best practice is to import the module name as a shorted name, so that you can use it without typing/reading overhead:

```py
import controllers as C

...
C.UserControler = ...
```

If you want to expose the names in the current module so that they can be further imported, then you can filter the contents of the imported module and set the respective keys in the dicionary returned by `globals()`.

```
import controllers

for controller_var in dir(controllers):
   if controller_var.endswith("Controller"):
        globals()[controller_var] = getattr(controllers, controller_var)
del controllers
```

(this approach is most likely what you want)

## if the names are files inside a folder

If the names you want to import are independent Python files inside a package (that is, you have a "controllers" folder and "UserController.py", etc... inside it, Then you have to resort to locating the package-folder and use a function to import the modules by their string name. The built-in `__import__` function can be used, but modern code would be better using `importlib.import_module`

The `pathlib.Path` class can facilitate directory and filename manipulation:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from importlib import import_module
import controllers

package_path = Path(controllers.__file__.parent)

for file_path in pakage_path.iterdir():
    if file_path.stem.endswith("Controller"):
         globals()[file_path.stem] = import_module(f"controllers.{file_path.stem}")
del file_path, package_path, import_module, Path
```

## Making dynamic names available to your program

In so far your question is answered, but note that the solutions above will be of little to no utility in a solid program, unless your intent is just to expose the names in the importing module to components that further import this module itself.

That is because to actually *use* the imported classes, you will have to type their name, hardcoding it in code. So, if the source code already contains references to these classes, they might just as well be explicitly imported (or you might use the "abreviated module name", I proposed at the very start - `import controllers as C`.

If they were in distinct files, the code in the second section could be of use, because importing the files makes then run, and trigger any registry or initialization actions that might be in their code. Other than that, just for making the names available, this would be just as useless.

Now, if you want to be able to instantiate all your Controller classes in sequence, or make then available as choices to the user or other parts of your code, you'd better just make then available in a data-structure, rather than names in the current module.  What makes then available as names is the updating of the  `globals()` dictionaries, in all snippets above.

Just use an ordinary dictionary, instead of `globals()`, and whatever code have to iterate over all  "Controller" classes can use that dictionary instead.

Comment: Yes, they are identifiers inside a file. will try the one with a loop. Btw, is ```del controlers``` a typo?

Comment: yes, of course it is a typo. But I hope you got the idea with the `del` statements: they are not needed, but since you want to create a namespace with meaningful names, there is no reason to let behind unused names.

Comment: It just got a bit longer, explaining the cases were this can be useful at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir`:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("my_folder"):
    if 'contains' in file:
         import file
```